# Observable / Subject loosing subscribers in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, behaviorsubject

I'm using a Static variable in my Class to store an initialised `BehaviourSubject`, so that I can provide a default, while I load the user's settings from the server.

*(have put a cut down example version below)*

```
@Injectable
export class AppSettings {
   // Using a static to globalize our variable to get 
   // around different instances making lots of requests.
   static readonly currency: Subject<string> = new BehaviorSubject('USD');

   // Return a property for general consumption, but using
   // a global/static variable to ensure we only call once. 
   get currency(): Observable<string> { return AppSettings.currency; }


   loadFromServer():any {
      // Broadcast the currency once we get back 
      // our settings data from the server.
      this.someService.getSettings().subscribe(settings => {
         // this is called lastly, but AppSettings.currency.observers
         // seems to show as an empty array in the Inspector?? 
         AppSettings.currency.next(settings.currency);
      });
   }
}
```

When I subscribe to it later in my code, it will run through it once (since it's a `BehaviorSubject`), but it won't fire after that.

```
export class myComponent {
   public currency: string;

   constructor(settings: AppSettings) {
       // Called once with the default 'USD'
       settings.currency.subscribe(currency => {
           // only gets here once, before loadFromServer
           console.log(currency);
           this.currency = currency;
       });

       // Load from the server and have our subscription
       // update our Currency property.
       settings.loadFromServer();
   }
}
```

The `loadFromServer()` is working exactly as expected, and the `AppSettings.currency.next(settings.currency)` line is being called, and after the first event.  What is interesting however, is at this point, the `AppSettings.currency.observables[]` is empty, when it was previously filled in.

My thoughts we're initially an issue of different instances, but I'm using a static variable (have even tried a global one) to avoid different instances.

This is the current workflow...

1. `myComponent.constructor` subscribes
2. that subscription fires, giving the default 'USD'
3. the server data is loaded, and `AppSettings.currency.next(settings.currency)` is called
4. ...then...nothing....

I'm expecting that at part 4 the Observer that subscribed in part 1 would be fired again, but it isn't, making my glorified Observer a constant.  :(

Am I missing something?

Comment: is there a typo? I see setting.loadFromServer. shouldn't it be settings. ?

Comment: that was a typo, but the example is a summarized version of my code anyway, as I just wrote an abridged version on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel sheepish....

Figured out the issue was due to my `import` statement having the (wrong) file suffix on the file reference.  So, in the `myComponent` file I had...

`import { AppSettings } from './settings`**.js**`';`

While everywhere else I have been using (the correct)

`import { AppSettings } from './settings';`

which was causing WebPack to compiling two versions of the class, the TypeScript *and* the (compiled) Javascript version, thus creating two different instances.  I managed to see an `AppSettings_1` somewhere, that lead me down the rabbit hole to finally gave it away.